# What is the fastest way to track list of top visible divs under the fixed header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm working on layout, which you may visually imagine using a link below:

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Porg.png)

Fixed header is a div with `position: fixed`. Which means, that scrolling process hides elements under it (that's why it's transparent on my image for illustration purposes). I need to track a list of vertically top elements (other divs) on a page, which are still visible. Using my layout example, I need a list of `red` elements. They may be positioned in any way.

Expected result is JavaScript function, which returns an array of elements. Behind the scenes, the solution should definitely track `window.onScroll` event and somehow effectively maintain ability to fetch the result in the fastest possible way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the red divs are of the same parent you can do this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#parentDiv').children().each(function () {

        if($(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight() < $("#parentDiv").position().top + $("#parentDiv").outerHeight()) {
             // add them to array
        }

    });
})
```

1. This will run every time the page is scrolled, the parent div's children are then iterated through (this is costly, but if you dynamically add elements to the page then this will also work with slight tweaking).
2. Check each child's bottom position and compare that with the bottom position of the fixed header (top + outerHeight), if true then the elements bottom is less than the header's bottom and therefore underneath the header.
3. Do as you wish after that, adding their Jquery references into an array if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I created the function `getDivs` which will return the jQuery object with the specific divs.

You can edit the `$allDivs` variable inside the function to any jQuery object you wish to check

Please check my snippet below:

```js
var
$allDivs = $('#container > .column > div'), // Divs you want to check
$header = $('#header');

function getDivs() {
  return $allDivs
  .filter(function() {
    var
    $this = $(this),
    top = parseInt($this.offset().top, 10),
    bottom = top + $this.outerHeight(),
    scrTop = $header.offset().top + $header.outerHeight();

    if (top <= scrTop && bottom >= scrTop)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  });
}

$allDivs.removeClass('under');
getDivs()
.addClass('under');

$(window).scroll(function() {
  $allDivs.removeClass('under');
  
  getDivs()
  .addClass('under');
  
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 1300px;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.column {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.column > div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 1 1 100px;
}

#col1 { margin: 100px 0 0; }

#col3 { margin: 30px 0 0; }

#col1 > div { flex: 1 1 75px; }

#col2 > div { flex: 1 1 200px; }

.under { background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  Header
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="col1" class="column">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div id="col2" class="column">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div id="col3" class="column">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```